# Cannot connet MongoDB on Yii2 [ 'Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found' ]

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2, mamp-pro

I'm starting to use Yii2, and I want to connecting it with Mongodb.
So I tried to follow the instruction from both website documents.

And seem everything good because I already made a simple test on my normal localhost, and it working fine.

but when I want to testing it on Yii2 Advanced template, I cannot connect Yii2 with Mongodb.

it's always say the error about:

```
PHP Fatal Error 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found'
in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yii/yii2-advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb/Connection.php:355
```

Here the code on /yii2-advanced/frontend/web/index-test.php that I use:

```
<?php
// NOTE: Make sure this file is not accessible when deployed to production
if (!in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ['127.0.0.1', '::1'])) {
   die('You are not allowed to access this file.');
}

defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'test');

require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/bootstrap.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../config/bootstrap.php');

$mongodb = new MongoClient("mongodb://root:1234567890@localhost:27017/yii2advanced");
$users = $mongodb->yii2advanced->users;
$user = $users->findOne();
print_r($user);

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/test-local.php');

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

PS:

- I'm using MAMP PRO on Mac.
- I can get the good result of $user when I made a test on htdocs/index.php.
- I'm sorry for my bad English.

Comment: is mongo extenstion enable in your server?

Comment: Why are you trying to connect to Mongo in you index?
you have to install the extension and then configure it in your config file, then use the MongoDb extension as you need in their namespaces, after all you can use it in your model and controller but you must not define anything in your index file.

Comment: I just make a test actually.

Answer (score 0):

After I searching and follow many instruction on the internet,
I found the links below are useful for the new installer.

https:// docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/?_ga=1.258923597.615822406.1480144338

https://bigseadesign.com/web-development/how-to-install-mongo-php-osx-mamp/

https://www.hugethoughts.com/blog/setup-mongodb-mamp-5-minutes/

But I would notice to you that, when you wanna add extension=mongodb.so on the php.ini configuration
I do recommend you to checking and put the correct path that you were installed MongoDB PHP Driver because,

When I were installed "MongoDB PHP Driver" via brew

( http:// php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.homebrew.php )

on Mac Os they will installed it this path:

```
/usr/local/opt/phpXX-mongodb/
```

So php.ini on your MAMP have to call mongo extention like this:

```
extension=/usr/local/opt/php56-mongodb/mongodb.so
```

By the way.,
Please note that the new "MongoDB PHP Driver" is "mongodb.so"
not "mongo.so" because mongo.so already deprecated.